# pyramid deployment in nginx

Tags: python, nginx, pyramid

I am using nginx to serve a website on a server configured as follows:

```html
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.com
  root /var/www/html;
  error_log /var/log/test.log;
  
  location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html?$query_string; 
   }
   
   location /rest/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:6543;
   }
}
```

the / location only has static html and js files while the /rest/ location should go to the pyramid app but that part is not working.

how do I pass the /rest/ location to pyramid on http://localhost:6543?

nginx access log:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2018:15:20:39 +0800] "GET /rest HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"

nothing in nginx error log

Comment: show us nginx logs(error.log/access.log). Also hope your application is running on `localhost:6543`.

Comment: the application is running fine on http://localhost:6543

Comment: fyi - the / location contains js and html for an angular app and it is making calls to the pyramid application which should be in the /rest/ location

Comment: Did you get the fix your issue. Do you mind giving the solution to community?

Comment: @kishorPawar - Your answer actually helped me out. Besides those headers you mentioned, I also had to add X-Forwarded-Proto in the list of headers to forward to the proxy. The complete set of headers are:

proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

Thanks.

Comment: I am glad it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, See my observations and their possible solutions below

1. You have declared `location` as `/rest/` (with slash at the end)
   A. Try hitting `/rest/` url. (with slash at the end)
2. When you hit `/rest` you got `502` error from your `access logs`.
   A. `502` error indicates that **the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server.**
   In simple words, see what code is running on `/rest` and if it is responding as expected.

besides these, consider adding headers to your `/rest/` location.

```
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```